# Ignoring stdout of child process, dangerous?

Tags: c#, windows, process

I have an application which starts 1-45 processes (job dependent) and communicates with them via named pipes. I'm only interested in the `stderr` of the child processes and have no interest in redirecting the `stdout` of the processes.

I have written code that does exactly this, I redirect `stderr` and not `stdout` and everything works as expected. And when I say that I mean, I get the redirected `stderr` and I don't see any `stdout` appearing on the parent processes console nor do I get any deadlocks due to not redirecting `stdout`.

> My concern here is, where is the `stdout` of the child processes
>   going? The processes tend to dump a lot of text to `stdout` and I'm
>   afraid they're filling up some internal `buffer` which is going to
>   cause the child processes to `block` when writing to `stdout`.

In the past I also redirected `stdout` and just dumped (did nothing) the data provided from the async event.
But doing this had a severe consequence. 
As stated above I communicate via `named pipes` with the child 
processes. What I noticed is when I redirect `stdout` it hammers the performance of the parent processes `write` operations over the `named pipes`.

When not redirecting `stdout` the write times are usually `< 1ms` but after redirecting `stdout` the times jump to `> 4s`...

> ***My question is, is it safe to only redirect `stderr`?***

Below is part of the code I use to wrap the `Process`. I also use that well established `extension` method for `await`ing the process to complete. I didn't post that but I can if you're not familiar with it.

```
public class ChildProcess
{
    public async Task StartProcessAsync( string executablePath, CancellationToken token = default )
    {
        if ( !File.Exists( executablePath ) )
            throw new FileNotFoundException( "The specified rip executable path does not exist", executablePath );

        using var process = new Process( );          
        process.StartInfo.FileName = executablePath;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        await StartProcess( process, StdErrorOutput, token ).ConfigureAwait( false );

        static void StdErrorOutput( object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args )
        {
            if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( args.Data ) ) return;
        }
    }

    private Task StartProcess( Process process,
        DataReceivedEventHandler? stderr, CancellationToken token = default )
    {
        return Task.Run( async ( ) =>
        {
            try
            {
                if ( stderr is object )
                    process.ErrorDataReceived += stderr;

                if ( !process.Start( ) )
                    throw new ApplicationException( $"Failed to start '{process.StartInfo.FileName}'" );

                if ( stderr is object )
                    process.BeginErrorReadLine( );

                await process.WaitForExitAsync( token ).ConfigureAwait( false );
            }
            finally
            {
                SafeKill( );

                if ( stderr is object )
                    process.ErrorDataReceived -= stderr;
            }

            void SafeKill( )
            {
                try
                {
                    if ( !process.HasExited )
                    {
                        process.Refresh( );

                        if ( stderr is object )
                            process.CancelErrorRead( );

                        process.Kill( );
                    }
                }
                catch ( Exception ex )
                {
                    Console.WriteLine( ex );
                }
            }

        } );
    }
}
```

**Edit**

After reading the comment left by Eryk Sun I decided to dig into the `Process` source code to see if I could figure out what's happening. Mainly I was interested in seeing how the `STARTUPINFO` structure was populated when only specifying redirection of one of the `std` `streams`.

I removed a bunch of code I wasn't interest in. From what I can tell, if I set `RedirectStandardError` to `true` and specify `RedirectStandardOutput` to `false` the `STARTIPINFO` structures `hStdOutput` member is set to `stdout`. This results in the `StandardOutput` property on the `Process` `class` to be `null`.

If `RedirectStandardOutput` was set to `true` the output from the child process is redirected through a `pipe`. A `StreamReader` instance is then created and assigned to `StandardOutput`. The `StreamReader` then reads from the `pipe` created to attain the output from the child process.

> So if the `HANDLE` is being set to `stdout` when
>   `RedirectStandardOutput` is set to `false`, why do I not see the
>   output on the parent processes console window? Where is the output
>   going?

#### System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess

[source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.Windows.cs)

```
SafeFileHandle? childInputPipeHandle = null;
SafeFileHandle? parentOutputPipeHandle = null;

if (startInfo.RedirectStandardInput || startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput || startInfo.RedirectStandardError)
{
    if (startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput)
    {
        CreatePipe(out parentOutputPipeHandle, out childOutputPipeHandle, false);
    }
    else
    {
         childOutputPipeHandle = new SafeFileHandle(Interop.Kernel32.GetStdHandle(Interop.Kernel32.HandleTypes.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), false);
    }

    startupInfo.hStdOutput = childOutputPipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle();
    startupInfo.dwFlags = Interop.Advapi32.StartupInfoOptions.STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
}

/* Code starting the process removed */

if (startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput)
{
    Encoding enc = startInfo.StandardOutputEncoding ?? GetEncoding((int)Interop.Kernel32.GetConsoleOutputCP());
    _standardOutput = new StreamReader(new FileStream(parentOutputPipeHandle!, FileAccess.Read, 4096, false), enc, true, 4096);
 }
```

Comment: `What I noticed is when I redirect stdout it hammers the performance of the parent processes` That's odd. Were you actually redirecting to your own console or something? I would recommend redirecting and asynchronously dumping the stdout if you don't care about it; stdout *does* have a buffer and it *can* fill up.

Comment: @StephenCleary No, when I was redirecting `stdout` over fears of the internal buffer filling up,  I just dumped the data. And by that I mean I had an empty event handler. I really don't understand why redirecting `stdout` has such a large negative impact  on the `write` performance over `named pipes` on the server side.

Comment: I also do not know why that would affect performance so strongly. Assuming you're doing continuous asynchronous read-and-dump in an independent loop, I wouldn't expect it to bog down the parent process that much.

Comment: @StephenCleary I've tried it a number of ways. One was an independent loop which asynchronously read from the `stream` and the other was using the asynchronous read `BeginOutputReadLine`  and its associated `event handler`. One thing of note when redirecting `stdout` is there is almost a linear relationship between the number of running child processes and `named pipe` `write` performance.

Comment: I don't know what .NET does, but if a standard handle is left as `NULL` in the  `STARTUPINFO` that's passed to `CreateProcessW`, the CRT startup code in a native Windows application just configures the corresponding standard file descriptor (0, 1, or 2) with an OS handle of -1, and the corresponding `FILE` stream (`stdin`, `stdout`, or `stderr`) isn't valid, not until the process reopens it to a valid file via `[_w]freopen`. There's no buffer that fills up.

Comment: But some programs may fail if a standard file isn't valid, in which case the parent can just set the standard handle value to a handle for the "//./NUL" device.

Comment: @ErykSun That's honestly the best news I've heard all day. Do you happen to know  off the top of your head if `Windows Internals` makes mention of this? I'm going to look at the source code for the `Process` class and see what is does

Comment: @ErykSun So I dug into the code for the `Process` class.  If I set `RedirectStandardOutput` to `false` the `hStdOutput` member of the `STARTUPINFO` structure is set to `stdout`. Which makes me question why I don't see the child processes output appearing on my parents processes console window.

Comment: Yes, in [`StartWithCreateProcess`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/1c048bdfc7b7e4dc9b6d8170b63052695b1d8459/src/libraries/System.Diagnostics.Process/src/System/Diagnostics/Process.Windows.cs#L502), if either of the other standard handles is redirected to a pipe, then it uses the current value from `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)`. But you shouldn't see the output because you're setting `CreateNoWindow = true`. That passes the creation flag `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`, which makes the child process allocate a new console session (conhost.exe instance) that creates no window.

Comment: @ErykSun So the million dollar question, *is it safe for me to ignore stdout of the child process in this case*?

Comment: Did you try it without `CreateNoWindow = true`? If you see it happily printing to the parent's console in that case, then there's no reason that it won''t be just as happy printing to a console screen buffer that has no window. The only difference is that the no-window console isn't rendering the screen buffer to a window.

Comment: @ErykSun Yes I can confirm setting `CreateNoWinow = false` does cause the child output to show on the parents console window. Thanks a ton for your help. If you want to post an answer i'll accept it.